# How intersection two MapReduce result

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce

I need to find the same words in two files. I use spark, java.

Task:
For two text files count the number of words that occur simultaneously in the first and in the second file. The result is saved to a file as key-value pairs, where key is the number of common words, value is the word itself.

question: 
how to do it correctly? 
I first find the words and the number of occurrences of that word in the first file using wordcount, similar for the second file. 
How to combine them leaving only the common between the first and second?

I join them and i got this:
(test,(1,1))
(spark,(1,2))

I need to get a minimum of two values i.e.
(test,1)
(spark,1)

How to do it correctly?

[My edit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aiXC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is scala but should be simple enough to translate to java:

```
val f1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file1")
val w1 = f1.flatMap(_.split(" ")).toDF().distinct()
val f2 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file2")
val w2 = f2.flatMap(_.split(" ")).toDF().distinct()
val result = w1.join(w2,w1("value")===w2("value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the (word,count) in two dataframes `df1` and `df2` you can use an inner join. In spark joins are inner equijoins by default, something like

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("word"))
```

will  do the trick (it depends how you named the word/count from df1 and df2, you may need to rename some of the columns).